# Oracle SQL: select count of multiple distinct fields

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I need to `select` `id`, `type` and count of rows with unique `id-type` combinations.

So I tried something like this:

```
SELECT ID,
       CASE
         WHEN /**/ THEN 'FIRST'
         WHEN /**/ THEN 'ANOTHER'
         ELSE 'ELSE'
         END AS TYPE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ID, TYPE)

FROM   PRODUCTS

GROUP BY ID, TYPE;
```

Also the problem is type calculated while processing the query, so when I tried to do something like:

```
SELECT ID,
       /*SOMETHING*/ END AS TYPE,
       COUNT(*)

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ID,TYPE FROM PRODUCTS GROUP BY ID,TYPE);
```

I got this:

```
 ORA-00904: "TYPE": invalid identifier
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
       (CASE WHEN /**/ THEN 'FIRST'
             WHEN /**/ THEN 'ANOTHER'
             ELSE 'ELSE'
        END) AS TYPE
FROM  PRODUCTS;
```

Then you can transform it as subquery ::

```
SELECT ID, TYPE, COUNT(*)
FROM ( <QUERY HERE> ) T
GROUP BY ID, TYPE;
```

Comment: oh, sry, I guess it's something that I need, but I'll check, thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me, returning count 1 for all rows

Comment: @TyulpanTyulpan. . . That is how `DISTINCT` would work. If you don't want unique count then remove `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, seems like it works as expected now without the distinct, otherwise count would be senseless)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT ID,
       (CASE WHEN /**/ THEN 'FIRST'
             WHEN /**/ THEN 'ANOTHER'
             ELSE 'ELSE'
        END) AS TYPE,
       COUNT(*)
FROM PRODUCTS
GROUP BY ID, 
         (CASE WHEN /**/ THEN 'FIRST'
               WHEN /**/ THEN 'ANOTHER'
               ELSE 'ELSE'
        END);
```

Comment: Actually there are 70 lines in the function) can I avoid code duplication and to check the type just once (it's gonna be a performance issue, isn't it?)?

Comment: Also I'm getting ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression